# Change case of first letter in every cell in spreadsheet

Tags: python, perl, bash, csv, openoffice-calc

I have many cells which I'd like to convert such that the first letter in every cell is capitalized. E.g. `cook, chef, fireman` becomes `Cook, Chef, Fireman`.

- I have the spreadsheet in OpenOffice.org, but it seems to only have options for "all uppercase" or "all lowercase".
- I can edit it in OpenOffice.org or export to a CSV and edit the CSV with a BASH script, if OpenOffice.org cannot do this.

How can I change the first letter of every cell in the spreadsheet to uppercase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an awk script that will do what you want (I think).

Here is my test intput (test.input):

```
cook, chef, fireman
cook, chef, fireman
cook, chef, fireman
cook, chef, fireman
house, farm, road
```

My awk script (up.awk):

```
# from: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Join-Function.html
function join(array, start, end, sep, result, i){
         if (sep == "")
            sep = " "
         else if (sep == SUBSEP) # magic value
            sep = ""
         result = array[start]
         for (i = start + 1; i <= end; i++)
            result = result sep array[i]
         return result
}
BEGIN {
    FS="\n";
}
{
    # split input on newline
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # split line on the commas
        size = split($i, s, ",")
        for(ii=1;ii<=size;ii++) {
            # trim whitespace
            gsub(/[[:space:]]*/,"",s[ii])
            # uppercase first char and glue it back together
            s[ii] = toupper(substr(s[ii], 0, 1)) substr(s[ii], 2)
        }
        # join array back and print it out
        print join(s, 1, size, ", ")
    }
}
```

How I run the script:
`awk -f up.awk test.input >test.output`

The output in my test.output:

```
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Cook, Chef, Fireman
House, Farm, Road
```

Comment: When I run the script, it just deletes "a", "e", and "i" from the file.

Comment: @Village if you could post the lines of csv file in question, that would be helpful, before and after.  Also, it is possible maybe there is some difference in awk versions.  I am running "awk version 20070501".

Comment: I have used your CSV file. It changes to: "ok, hf, firmn".

Comment: You are probably on ubuntu, you could do "sudo apt-get install gawk".  Then use gawk instead.

Answer (score 8):

I happen to do this task. You have to install [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm#SYNOPSIS) and [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) modules.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook = $parser->Parse('Book1.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {

            my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            # "ucfirst lc" make sure that only the first letter is capitalized
            # if you dont like that just remove lc
            $worksheet->AddCell( $row, $col, ucfirst lc $cell->value() );

        }
    }
}

# ofcouse save your work
$workbook->SaveAs('Book2.xls');
```

Comment: I recommended these modules, but you gave the example.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you just need to udpate to a more recent version. I'm using LibreOffice 3.4.4 and I see `Format -> Change Case -> Sentence case` which I'd say does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 6):

Is Perl an option? There's a module in the CPAN archive called [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) that can also handle OpenOffice spreadsheets too.

You basically read in the spreadsheet, search the cells, modify the ones you want, and the create a ***new*** spreadsheet with the modified data. You cannot directly modify an Excel spreadsheet. I don't know if this applies to OpenOffice documents.

I used this before to read and write Excel spreadsheets, but that was a while ago. However, this module can handle your situation without first having to save the spreadsheet in CSV format.

Answer (score 3):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pwe 's/(?:^|,)\s*\K([a-z])/\U$1/g;' file.csv > fileout.csv
```

You can also use in-place edit with the `-i` switch. E.g. `perl -pi.bak -we ...`

Longer version, using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS). This module will (probably) treat your csv files with more care.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
        binary  => 1,
        eol     => $/,
    });

my $file = shift;
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {
    s/([a-z])/\U$1/ for @$row;
    $csv->print (*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Run it with: `perl script.pl file.csv > fileout.csv`

Answer (score 2):

you could do something pretty dodgy with python or any other language.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

lastchar = ""
orig_csv = open("yourfile.csv", "r")
new_csv = open("newfile.csv", "w")
for line in orig_csv:
    for char in line:
        if lastchar == ",":
            new_csv.write(char.upper())
        else:
            new_csv.write(char)
orig_csv.close()
new_csv.close()
```

This assumes that none of the fields are enclosed in quotes, because it'll just upcase everything after a comma.

Failing that, you'll want to actually use a csv library.

Comment: Which part doesn't work? In fairness, it's wholly untested. I just bashed it out off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using, or if you upgrade to, OOo 3.3 there are options for this built in.
Mark all the cells you want to affect, then choose `Format -> Change Case -> Sentence case` and voila! See if that does the trick for you?

Answer (score 1):

Export it as a csv. Then do something like this.

```
#psuedo python
out=""
nums = [col numbers to capitalize]
for line in file.read_csv('input.csv'):
    for n in nums:
       line[n] = line[n].capitalize()
       out += ",".join(line) + "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write up a small `gawk` and `sed` combo to get title case -

```
gawk -v RS="[,\n]" -v ORS="" '
{a=substr($1,1,1); b=substr($1,2); print toupper(a)b" "; if (NR%3==0) print "\n"}' file | 
sed -e 's/ /, /g' -e 's/, *$//'
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
cook, chef, fireman
cook, chef, fireman
cook, chef, fireman
cook, chef, fireman
house, farm, road

[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk -v RS="[,\n]" -v ORS="" '
{a=substr($1,1,1); b=substr($1,2); print toupper(a)b" "; if (NR%3==0) print "\n"}' file | 
sed -e 's/ /, /g' -e 's/, *$//'
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Cook, Chef, Fireman
House, Farm, Road
```

Obviously this isn't the perfect solution, you might have to tweak it a little bit depending on how many rows of data you have or want. Changes to `NR%3` should be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
cat <<! | sed 's/\<[^,]*/\u&/g'
> cook, chef, fireman
> head cook, head chef, chief fireman
> house, farm, road
> !
Cook, Chef, Fireman
Head cook, Head chef, Chief fireman
House, Farm, Road
```

Probably GNU sed specific.